# Query for treeview

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, telerik, treeview

I have a query which is working fine.

Is it possible that if the table3's column(Child) is only related to table 1  to show it under table 1 and not under table 2, but at the same time another (Child) has a parent in table 2 (which usually is the case)  it will show under table 2 as its currently doing.

**In other words Child column is directly under Table2's row column name (Father), but occasionally it comes under Table1 with no relation to Table 2.**

How can I out put that in a query for a treeview? I am assuming that I will have to program   the out come in c# also with 3 for loops and in the second loop I can check if the column is grandchild or Child and make that as a second row or 2nd node of treeview, but I am having a problem building a query in sql. Any help is much appreciated.

The query below shows all Parent, then child then grand child(all well and working),  but what is desired is at times child takes place of a father.

```
declare @x as xml
set @x =
(
SELECT distinct  
Table1.AssetSysID, Table1.Asset_ID , Table1.FromLR, Table1.Asset_ID + ', ' + Table1.[Desc2] as GarndFather,
Table2.ACISysID ,Table2.PAssetSysID, Table2.FeatureName + ', ' + Table2.[DESC] AS Father,
Table3.ITMSysID  ,Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] as Child
FROM  Table1 left outer join 
Table2 ON Table1.AssetSysID = Table2.PAssetSysID left outer join 
Table3 ON Table1.AssetSysID = Table3.AssetSysID AND Table2.ACISysID = Table3.ACISysID
where (Table1.AssetType = @AssetType)
for xml auto,root('xml')
)
```

Asp.Net Telerik Treeview DataBinding Code:

```
<DataBindings>
      <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="Table1" TextField="Assets" ValueField="AssetSysID"  ToolTip="Asset" ImageUrl="~/Images/DeleteIco.png"/>
      <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="Table2" TextField="Feature" ValueField="ACISysID" ToolTip="Feature" ImageUrl="~/Images/CutIco.png"/>
       <telerik:RadTreeNodeBinding DataMember="Table3" TextField="Equipment" ValueField="ITMSysID" ToolTip="Equipment" ImageUrl="~/Images/EditIco.png"/>

    </DataBindings>
```

****Final Code:***

```
 select Table1.AssetObjID as "@AssetObjID",
           Table1.Asset_ID as "@Asset_ID",
           Table1.FromLR as "@FromLR",
           Table1.AssetType + ', ' + Table1.StreetName + ', ' +  Table1.FromMunicNo   as "@FirstRow",
           (
           select Table2.ACIObjID as "@ACIObjID",
                  Table2.PAssetObjID as "@PAssetObjID",
                  Table2.Feature_ID + ', ' + Table2.FeatureName   AS "@ChildOfFirstRow",
                  (
                  select Table3.ITMObjID as "@ITMObjID",
                         Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] as "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
                  from Table3
                  where Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID and 
                        Table2.ACIObjID = Table3.ACIObjID
                  for xml path('Table3'), type
                  )
           from Table2
           where Table1.AssetObjID = Table2.PAssetObjID
           for xml path('Table2'), type
           ),
(
           select Table3.ITMObjID as "@ITMObjID",
                         Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] as "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
                  from Table3
                  where Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID and 
                        Table2.ACIObjID <> Table3.ACIObjID
                  for xml path('Table3'), type
)
    from Table1
    where Table1.AssetType = 'xxxx'
    for xml path('Table1'), root('xml')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an Idea from [Mikael Eriksson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296869/tsql-query-for-tree-view-control-and-remove-empty-elements-from-an-xml-file) and help from team lead @ work

```
     select Table1.AssetObjID as "@AssetObjID",
               Table1.Asset_ID as "@Asset_ID",
               Table1.FromLR as "@FromLR",
               Table1.AssetType + ', ' + Table1.StreetName + ', ' +  Table1.FromMunicNo   as "@FirstRow",
               (
               select Table2.ACIObjID as "@ACIObjID",
                      Table2.PAssetObjID as "@PAssetObjID",
                      Table2.Feature_ID + ', ' + Table2.FeatureName   AS "@ChildOfFirstRow",
                      (
                      select Table3.ITMObjID as "@ITMObjID",
                             Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] as "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
                      from Table3
                      where Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID and 
                            Table2.ACIObjID = Table3.ACIObjID
                      for xml path('Table3'), type
                      )
               from Table2
               where Table1.AssetObjID = Table2.PAssetObjID
               for xml path('Table2'), type
               ),
(
               select Table3.ITMObjID as "@ITMObjID",
                             Table3.Item_ID + ',' + Table3.[DESC] as "@GrandChildOfFirstRow"
                      from Table3
                      where Table1.AssetObjID = Table3.AssetObjID and 
                            Table2.ACIObjID <> Table3.ACIObjID
                      for xml path('Table3'), type
)
        from Table1
        where Table1.AssetType = 'xxxx'
        for xml path('Table1'), root('xml')
```

So It goes something like this:

```
<Table1 atrributes......... FirstRow=".........."/>
<Table2 atrributes......... ChildOfFirstRow="..........">
<Table3 atrributes......... GrandChildOfFirstRow=".........."/>
</Table2>
<Table3 atrributes......... GrandChildOfFirstRow="This GrandChild took the importance as equal to ChildOfFirstRow"/>
```